# What is encoded in the first taproot enabled block?

Tags: block, taproot, op-return, encoding

There are a bunch of encoded messages in the first taproot enabled block in `op_return` outputs. What is encoded there?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at the mention of the the Genesis Block here. The Genesis Block is the zeroth block of the Bitcoin blockchain. The first Taproot-enabled block doesn't have anything to do with the Genesis block.

Comment: I see. Sorry wrong use of the word genesis then. I was under the impression the first activated block of Taproot was also called a genesis block!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know so alternative answers are welcome!

If you look at the [coinbase transaction](https://mempool.space/tx/3e1005f68bf7b18a58f1ef260283f0f19e1efb45c37b9ea94599a893021a0b78) in the block 709632 (mined by F2Pool) where full nodes started enforcing Taproot rules there is a scriptSig and 4 OP_RETURNs.

The scriptSig is:

`OP_PUSHBYTES_3 00d40a OP_PUSHBYTES_44 fabe6d6db2182a1a8634a5b5c8e4c9102f69b795db3d02e80064a0b007408cca80f68dc110000000f09f909f OP_PUSHBYTES_8 2f4632506f6f6c2f OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_5 00de920100`

I don't know what the messages are in the OP_RETURNs though one of the OP_RETURNs is presumably used for the RSK sidechain as it refers to `RSKBLOCK`.